# SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005 to 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Is it possible to switch from 2005 to 2008 including the databases made in 2005? Or would that give an error? I have tried this but it gives me error 26.

This is the error:

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)*

Comment: Have you verified 'that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.' ? See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Comment: Are you trying to migrate management studio (the client application) or SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to connect SQL Management Studio 2005 to a SQL2008R2 instance? explain better please;

sql server 2005 backups can be restored on 2008R2 without problems on most cases;

are both instances on the same computer? is SQL Browser started? remember that if you keep more than 1 sql server instance on the same computer it's better if you start the SQL Browser service

Comment: I deleted 2005 and installed 2008 but when I try to connect it gives that error. I did start SQL Browser

Comment: check if you are trying to connect to the SQL2008R2 instance with the 2005 SQL Management Studio instead of the 2008 version, I'm not 100% sure that deleting the instance does delete the related management studio (after all they don't require themselves eachother).

Comment: I got it to work with 2012 but its just one database that wont restore. Other dbs do but this one doesnt. Any idea on what it could be? It just doesnt show up when restoring.

Comment: you don't get any error message? try this query and check if there's any reference to that db: select * from sys.databases

Comment: I try to restore it and it doesnt show anything in the Restore plan window